# Qt Eclipse Integration and custom widget plugin

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, plugins, integration

What is the correct procedure to compile a custom widget with the Eclipse Integration plugin, under Windows with [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)?

I tried the following steps, but I cannot see the widget in the Widget Bar.

1. Installed Qt 4.6.1 for Win32 (with MinGW)
2. Installed Eclipse Helios 32-bit (tried with Galileo too)
3. Installed Qt Eclipse Integrator 1.6.1
4. Reconfigured Qt for Integration: `configure -release -qtnamespace QtCppIntegration`
5. Compiled plugin in release using Eclipse (tried with Creator too)
6. Copied DLL file e "a" file in folder `C:\eclipse\plugins\com.trolltech.qtcppdesignerplugins.win32.x86_1.6.1`
7. Launched `eclipse -clean` to reset plugins

Naturally the widget works well under `Qt Designer` and I can use it there correctly.

Comment: For what it is worth I think the recommended way these days is to use [Qt Creator] (https://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/). Personally I have quite satisfying results making a project in Qt Creator, then importing that in eclipse, editing GUI in Creator and code in eclipse. This also allows you to change from widgets to Qt Quick which I think will be worth your while even if it takes a few days to get used to the new approach.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Eclipse Integration and Qt Creator binaries for Windows are compiled with Visual C++, so MinGW compiled plugins won't work with them. 
The standalone Qt Designer is compiled with MinGW, that's why your plugin works with it.

You can recompile Qt Creator with MinGW, I'm not sure about Qt Eclipse Integration.